# How to convert an object to its literal string?

Tags: javascript

I have a string containing an object literal:

```
var literalStr = "{
     a: 1, 
     b: function(){return 'b'}
 }";
```

I can create an object from the string:

```
var obj = eval("(" + literalStr + ")");
```

Is there a simple way to get the literal string back from the object?

I am looking for something like `JSON.stringify()` but so it create the original literal with functions and properties names without quotes.

Comment: This is what [`toSource`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toSource) does - but it's Firefox-specific.

Comment: @akmidd you already have it in literalStr. Why can't you use it?

Comment: Because I want to get a literal from any object not only from those created by known literals.

Comment: Are you just asking out of curiosity, do you want such functionality for debugging or do you plan to actually use this in production?

Comment: Now I need it for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the non-standard [`toSource` method(s)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toSource). Notice that a cross-browser version is impossible, because some js engines provide no possibility to get the source string from a function.

Comment: "impossible".. strong word!

Comment: @Buchow_PHP: But I mean it. Check [perfectionkills.com/those-tricky-functions](http://web.archive.org/web/20130531031212/http://perfectionkills.com/those-tricky-functions/)

Answer (score 0):

```
function stringify(source) {
    if (typeof (source) == "object") {
        var str = "{";
        for (var key in source) {
            var value = source[key];
            str += key + ":" + stringify(value) + ",";
        }
        return str.substring(0,str.length-1) + "}";
    }
    return source.toString();
}
```

then

```
console.log(stringify(obj));
// writes "{a:1,b:function (){return 'b'}}"
```

[Demo in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8sqYr/)

Comment: I think this is much more complicated than that. For starters, it doesn't handle strings properly.

Comment: You can easily add `if(typeof(source)=="string")...`